# Left Join tables but then get fancy with the columns - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database with 2 tables and I am trying to join them in a specific way.

Table 1: Profile

Columns: friend_ID, gender, birthyear, hometown, checkins

Table 2: Education

Columns: friend_ID, school_name, school_type

I want to left join like so:

```
    SELECT 
       friend_ID, birthyear, checkins 
   FROM Friend_Profile 
   LEFT JOIN 
       Education on Profile.friend_ID = Education.friend_ID
```

Then I want to change birthyear to age (2013-birthyear) and code school_type into categories. 3 for 'Graduate School', 2 for 'College', 1 for 'High School' and 0 for 'Other or no data' and just keep the highest number for each row. (The education table often contains multiple rows representing different school_type for the same friend_ID.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Subtract birthyear from current year to get age and use case to replace school_type with the appropriate integer. You should be able to do it all inline with your SELECT statement.

Comment: I also don't want more than one row per friend_id showing up.  For example, if one friend_id has college and graduate school listed in two separate columns, I only want graduate school to show up and that friend_id should only appear once.  In addition, some friend_ids don't appear at all in the education table and should get a 0 instead of null

Comment: You could replace any return of null with zero and you could get the max school_type.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't see how I can *only* add the highest school_type for a given friend_id

Comment: If you only want the highest school_type, you could use max and group by together to ensure you're getting the largest number after you get the result from case. So case lets you get the numbers you need and max and group by looks for the highest one of all rows sharing the friend_id.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me an example of that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Had to make the tables and write the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I created the tables and ran the statement on localhost.

Education Table: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/2t86ar)

Profile Table: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/2t86ex)

Result after running below SQL statement: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/2t86k8)

```
SELECT profile.friend_id, birthyear, checkins, MAX( 
CASE WHEN school_type =  'High School'
THEN 1 
WHEN school_type =  'College'
THEN 2 
WHEN school_type =  'Graduate School'
THEN 3 
ELSE 0 
END ) AS school_type
FROM profile
LEFT JOIN education ON profile.friend_id = education.friend_ID
GROUP BY (
profile.friend_id
)
```

**Update:**

Use `YEAR(CURDATE())` to get the current year (2014), or replace it with 2013, if you want to work with last year. You can obviously add more fields to grab if there are any missing in the select statement that you want to add.

Result: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/2tc94b)

It shows 14 because I used `YEAR(CURDATE())` instead of 2013. You can change that based on what you need.

```
SELECT profile.friend_id, YEAR(CURDATE()) - birthyear as age, checkins, MAX( 
CASE WHEN school_type =  'High School'
THEN 1 
WHEN school_type =  'College'
THEN 2 
WHEN school_type =  'Graduate School'
THEN 3 
ELSE 0 
END ) AS school_type
FROM profile
LEFT JOIN education ON profile.friend_id = education.friend_ID
GROUP BY (
profile.friend_id
)
```

Comment: another question...is it possible to filter out all situations where birthyear is null and then do 2013-birthyear